# Search for log having value greater than certain time

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Below is the sample log:

```
2020-10-14 00:05:44,621 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...............
2020-10-14 00:05:45,560 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...............
2020-10-14 00:05:46,222 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...............
2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss .... server is started ............
```

Below is the desired output:

```
2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss .... server is started ............
```

When I use `awk` if it is exact time it will display the output otherwise it not displaying the output. Below is the code:

Not displaying output:

```sh
awk /'2020-10-14 00:05:46,607'/ '/home/notyo/application.log' | grep -e 'JBoss.*started'
```

Displaying output:

```sh
awk /'2020-10-14 00:05:46,608'/ '/home/notyo/application.log' | grep -e 'JBoss.*started'

2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss ....  server is started ............
```

Besides that I got to find a solution. Below works but not as expected.

Displaying output as expected:

```sh
grep -e 'JBoss.*started' '/home/notyo/application.log' | awk '$0 >= "2020-10-14 00:05:46,608"'

2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss .... server is started ............
```

Displaying output. Expecting that it should not display as using `>`

```sh
grep -e 'JBoss.*started' '/home/notyo/application.log' | awk '$0 > "2020-10-14 00:05:46,608"'

2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss .... server is started ............
```

Can I know why such behaviour. Could you advice what is the correct approach?

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in form of code, please do add samples of input and expected output for more clarity in your question too.

Comment: Hi the output i should get "2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...............". But i not sure am i doing it correctly

Comment: I am getting expected output in the 2nd part. But why having more also displaying the output. Usually >= should display the output but > shoud not right. As is my 2nd solution i provided is good or need imrprove?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi updated with sample input, output

Comment: Which is correct, `JBoss` or `JBoos`?

Comment: JBoss is the correct 1

Comment: wrt `awk /'2020-10-14 00:05:46,607'/` - I've seen several times where people put the script delimiters (`'`) **inside** the script like that instead of **around** the script where they belong and I'm extremely curious about where that idea is coming from. Is there a book or web site or something that's telling people to put the script delimiters inside of scripts (`/'foo'/`) instead of around the scripts (`'/foo/'`)?

Comment: i saw that online. So was using that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the strings with `$0 > "2020-10-14 00:05:46,608"`, it will compare the string `2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss .... server is started ............` with a string `2020-10-14 00:05:46,608` which returns true.

In order to compare only date and time portion, please try instead:

```
grep -e 'JBoss.*started' '/home/notyo/application.log' | awk '($1" "$2) > "2020-10-14 00:05:46,608"'
```

If you want to include the exact time above, please replace `>` with `>=`, which also works as you expect.

Comment: Great. As what i am expecting

Comment: is there posibilites to use single quotation instead of double quotation?

Comment: We cannot nest the single quotes within single quotes, so it will be better to use double quotes within the awk script.

Comment: thanks for the info and the answer which was my expectation

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for your advice. The precedence of string concatenation is higher than the relational operator. I've updated my answer for clarity with respect.

Answer (score 2):

Your command:

```
awk '$0 > "2020-10-14 00:05:46,608"'
```

is not working because you're comparing full record against date-time string, but you should be comparing `($1 " " $2)` against date-time string like this:

```
awk '($1 " " $2) > "2020-10-14 00:05:46,607"' file.log
2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss server is started ............
```

---

For proper time comparison, you may use this awk command with a call to `mktime` to convert date string into EPOCH time and then adding milli-sec value separately:

```
cat srchlog.awk

function convt(ts, ms) {
    ms = ts
    sub(/.*,/, "", ms)
    gsub(/[-:,]/, " ", ts)
    return mktime(ts) + ms/1000
}
BEGIN {
   sval = convt(dt)
}
/JBoss.*started/ && convt($1 " " $2) > sval
```

Then use it as:

```
awk -v dt='2020-10-14 00:05:46,607' -f srchlog.awk file.log
```

```
2020-10-14 00:05:46,608 debug  [org.jboss.as] ...JBoss server is started ............
```

And then:

```
awk -v dt='2020-10-14 00:05:46,608' -f srchlog.awk file.log
# no output
```

Comment: Hi, can i know is there a simpler way to do it like in a line. Can i know is my method i did was it wrong? => grep -e 'JBoss.*started' '/home/notyo/application.log' | awk '$0 > "2020-10-14 00:05:46,608"'